# Creating relationships in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Currently, I have 3 tables located in 1 database.

- Table #1: `patients`
- Table #2: `checkups`
- Table #3: `surgery`

Table #1 (`patients`) contains the following:

```
ID
First name
Last name
Born
Residence
Phone number
Date added*(to the database)*
```

Table #2 (`checkups`) contains the following:

```
Column1
Column2
Column3
Column4
Column5
Column6
Column7
Column8
Column9
Column10
```

Table #3 (`surgery`) contains the following:

```
Date
Clinique
Anesthesia
Comments
```

Column `ID` in Table 1(`patients`) is set as `PRIMARY Key` and `UNIQUE` index and is set as `INT(11)`.

The tables named `patients` will hold **unique** patients, obviously.

The table named `checkups` will hold data gathered following various checkups. 
This table can contain multiple rows, with different field values on each row, for the same **patient**.

**Example**:

- patient #43 can have 4 rows of data (4 checkups) in the checkups table.
- patient #21 can have 1 row of data (1 checkup) in the checkups table.
- patient #78 can have 11 rows of data (11 checkups) in the checkups table.

...and so on and so forth.

The table named `surgery` will hold patient data regarding surgery scheduling (when, where and so on). Similar to `checkups` table, each patient can have multiple rows in this table.

**Later goal**:

I plan on connecting and interacting with this database in an application I'm developing. I'd like to link the tables in such a way that when I select a patient in the application (patient will be visible in a `DBGrid`) all of his rows (checkups) from the `checkups` table will be displayed in another `DBGrid`, and all his surgery schedules will be similarly displayed in another `DBGrid`.

Same thing should happen when I select a different patient from the list.

**Question/issue:**

How do I link these tables/columns in such a way as to achieve the end result (written above)? I've started browsing through the MySQL manual but I can't seem to understand the relationships as explained there. Specifically the 1 to 1, 1 to multiple, identifying and non-identifying kinds.
Which ones should I be using for my goal?

I'm using mysql 8.0.3 (the community edition from their website) set as InnoDB and interacting through Workbench. Just opened up the MySQL Models tab and tinkering along with the EED Diagrams

I'd appreciate a well-written example, tutorial or some other source to read, other than the mysql manual section on this.

Comment: Downvotes without explanations are so useful. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like folks are voting to close as *Too Broad*. This is also a foul on Stack Overflow: *"[where is] a well-written example, tutorial or some other source to read"*. That's asking for off-site resources. But the question seems like a well written design question. Maybe you would have better luck at [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @jww Not seeing as how it is too broad but whatever. There are literally hundreds of question more poorly written out there that don't get this slamming. A lot of them with the same ask. A lot of answers similarly, that start out as examples and end up with added off-site resources to further elaborate. That's what I was reffering to. Guess people are just nitpicky. Fine, I'll close it myself. Anyway, thanks for your comment on the matter. I'll definitely check out your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about the "words" used to describe relationships.

The logic is pretty simple:

- A "checkup" has one patient.  So it should have a non-`NULL` `patientid` with a foreign key relationship to patients.
- A "surgery" has one patient.  So it should have a non-`NULL` `patientid` with a foreign key relationship to patients.

That you are implementing 0/1-many relationships is not really important.  The understanding of the business entities dictate what you need.